# How is this tag being added to the DOM so fast?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

See this short [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-chaplygin-qnbrq?file=/src/App.js) which is identical to the code here:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [tag, setTag] = useState(null);

  function changeTagState() {
    setTag(<div>I am a div</div>); //className="new"
    let divTag = window.document.querySelector(`div`);
    divTag.style.setProperty("color", "red");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={changeTagState}>Click to change tag state</div>
      {tag}
      {/* <div onClick={alterTag}>Alter tag</div> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Why is `divTag` not `null`? Why is it able to see, and apply classes to, `divTag`?

Here's what I thought would happen in `changeTagState`:

1. `setTag` executes.
2. It then tries to assign value to `divTag` by running `querySelector`.
3. `changeTagState` is finished and the whole component's run again. Only then is the new value of `tag` added to the DOM.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct, but there's one thing being missed: the `<div>` that exists and is being selected by `querySelector` is the *root element* (which is a `<div>`), not the `<div>` in `setTag`. Another example, see what happens when you log it:

```js
function App() {
  let [tag, setTag] = React.useState(null);

  function changeTagState() {
    setTag(<div>I am a div</div>);
    let divTag = window.document.querySelector(`div`);
    console.log(divTag);
    divTag.style.setProperty("color", "red");
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div onClick={changeTagState}>Click to change tag state</div>
      {tag}
      {/* <div onClick={alterTag}>Alter tag</div> */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

It would indeed be `null` if you tried to use a more specific selector that only existed on the newly created div:

```js
function App() {
  let [tag, setTag] = React.useState(null);

  function changeTagState() {
    setTag(<div className='the-dynamic-div'>I am a div</div>);
    let divTag = window.document.querySelector(`.the-dynamic-div`);
    divTag.style.setProperty("color", "red");
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div onClick={changeTagState}>Click to change tag state</div>
      {tag}
      {/* <div onClick={alterTag}>Alter tag</div> */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried to recreate what was happening in my project where it really is able to see the newly-created tags before they're added to the DOM. I will leave this question and try and recreate the problem.